# Remote validation doesn't pass data to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, remote-validation

I have model:

```
public class MyModel
...fields
[Remote(ActionName, ControllerName)]
public string SomeNumber { get; set; }
..fields
```

And have a action in ControllerName controller:

```
public JsonResult ActionName(string someNumber)
{...}
```

But when actions is invoked the parameter someNumber is allways null.
And when I try to debug it I get

```
GET /ControllerName/ActionName?MyModel.SomeNumber =34189736
```

How can I make it work?
(I can't pass whole model MyModel, and cant change MyModel.SomeNumber name of field in my view)

**UPD.** Input in my view:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.SomeNumber" data-val-remote-url="/ControllerName/ActionName" id="MyModel_SomeNumber" name="MyModel.SomeNumber" type="text" value="34189734" class="valid">
```

**UPD** solved! :)
I create new model with single field SomeNumber and use prefix:

```
SomeNumber([Bind(Prefix = "MyModel")]MySingleFieldModel model)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using nested `ViewModels`, you'll need to accept the parent `ViewModel` as the argument in your `Validation` action. For example:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel User {get; set; }

    //....
}

public class UserViewModel 
{
    [Remote("UniqueUsername", "Validation")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //....
}
```

In ValidationController:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{ 
     public JsonResult UniqueUsername(ParentViewModel Registration) 
     {
        var Username = Registration.User.Username; //access the child view model property like so

        //Validate and return JsonResult

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using you model as the parameter.
So that it could bind the value to it.

```
public JsonResult ActionName(MyModel model)
{
    //...
    model.SomeNumber;
    //...

   return Json(validationResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't invoke my action anymore.

Comment: have you added the jsonrequestbehaviour flag? check updated answer

Comment: OP said he cant pass whole model MyModel

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult ActionName(string SomeNumber)
{...}
```

I think you may need to match case on your input parameter.

Comment: Easy way to solve this is to crank up Fiddler and check what parameters are being sent in the GET request query string. Your validation action should match those parameters. You shouldn't have to create another view model.